# HttpWebRequest GetRequestStream() - Thread was being aborted Error Message

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, httpwebrequest

I have a service that runs a lot of conccurent operations, and makes outboudn requests using HttpWebRequest.

I occasionally get an exception from the GetRequestStream() call that gives the following stack trace:

```
Thread was being aborted.
at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOneNative(SafeHandle waitableSafeHandle, UInt32 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean hasThreadAffinity, Boolean exitContext)
at System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne(SafeHandle waitableSafeHandle, Int64  millisecondsTimeout, Boolean hasThreadAffinity, Boolean exitContext)
at System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.WaitForCompletion(Boolean snap)
at System.Net.Connection.SubmitRequest(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean forcedsubmit)
at System.Net.ServicePoint.SubmitRequest(HttpWebRequest request, String connName)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SubmitRequest(ServicePoint servicePoint)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
//Rest of stack trace is path to my internal call
```

The code I am using to make the outbound request that is causing this issue is the following:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.PathToOutboundAPI.com/ApiCall);
request.Method = "POST";
request.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", Action);
request.ContentType = "text/xml";
request.KeepAlive = false;
request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
request.ServicePoint.ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 0;    //Dont want Connections staying open
var soapRequest = CreateSoapEnvelope();

byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(soapRequest);

string str = string.Empty;
Stream rs = default(Stream);
WebResponse response = default(WebResponse);
StreamReader reader = default(StreamReader);
try
{
    rs = request.GetRequestStream();
    rs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    response = request.GetResponse();
    reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    str = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
catch (WebException exception)
{
//Handle Appropriately
}
catch(Exception exception)
{
    //Handle Appropriately
}
finally
{
    if (rs != null)
    {
        rs.Close();
        rs.Dispose();
    }

    if (reader != null)
    {
        reader.Close();
        reader.Dispose();
    }

    if (response != null)
    {
        response.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: The `dispose()` method calls `close()` internally for those objects. Consider implementing a `using` block instead.

Comment: Is this what is causing this issue?

Comment: No, just a suggestion.

Comment: Is this code executing in a background thread? And what exception is thrown? The "Thread was being aborted" is the message. Need the exception type.

Comment: Is it an IIS application?

Comment: @JimMischel, This is executing on a background thread, and my logs failed to record the Exception type unfortunately so I am not sure at this time. I need to catch it again.

Comment: @Alan yes, this is an IIS application, it is a WCF service using .NET 4

Answer (score 0):

Execution thread was terminated by IIS. Change the execution timeout value to a very large value or disable it in one of the following ways:

1. Change Idle Time-out value of your application in IIS app pool to a large value, or 0 (zero) to disable it.
2. Add `<httpRuntime executionTimeout="1800"/>` within `<system.web>` section of your application